# What notification types are supported for changes.watch?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to set up a file watcher on a particular folder in Google Drive. Unfortunately, webhooks won't satisfy our use case, so I'm trying to see if the API supports other methods of push-based change notifications (such as WebSockets). The docs for `/changes/watch` indicate that you can submit a `type` parameter as part of the request body:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/watch

But the possible values for `type` don't appear to be enumerated anywhere, and all I can find in examples is that they all set this to `web_hook` when requesting a web hook callback.

What are the allowed values of `type`? Is it just `web_hook`?

Comment: To clarify, I know that I can poll the API regularly for pull-based change notifications, but this folder won't often change except in short bursts and I'd like to respond to those changes as they come in instead of as a single block, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported type as specified in [Drive Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) is :"web_hook":

> A type property string set to the value web_hook.

Comment: Arg, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks for clarifying